# No Pages getting crawled - scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

The following spider code in Scrapy was developed to be used to crawl pages from americanas website:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    import scrapy
    import urllib
    import re
    import webscrape.items
    import time
    from urlparse import urljoin
    from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

    class AmericanasSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "americanas"
    start_urls = ('http://www.americanas.com.br/loja/226795/alimentos-e-bebidas?WT.mc_id=home-menuLista-alimentos/',)
    source = webscrape.items.ImportSource ("Americanas")

    def parse (self, response):
        ind = 0
        self.source.submit()       
        b = []
        for c in response.xpath ('//div[@class="item-menu"]/ul'):
            c1 = re.sub('[\t\n]','', c.xpath('//span [@class="menu-heading"]/text()').extract()[ind])
            if (c1):
                x = webscrape.items.Category(c1)
                x.submit()
                for b in c.xpath ('li'):
                    b1 = webscrape.items.Category( b.xpath('a/text()').extract()[0])
                    if (b1):
                        b1.setParent(x.getID())
                        b1.submit()
                        link = b.xpath ('@href').extract()
                        urla = urljoin (response.url, link)
                        request = scrapy.Request (urla, callback = self.parse_category)
                        request.meta['idCategory'] = b1.getID ()
                        yield request
                        for a in b.xpath ('ul/li/a/text()'):
                            a1 = webscrape.items.Category( a.extract())
                            a1.setParent(b1.getID())
                            a1.submit()
                            link = a.xpath ('@href').extract()
                            urla = urljoin (response.url, link)
                            request = scrapy.Request (urla, callback = self.parse_category)
                            request.meta['idCategory'] = a1.getID ()
                            yield request
                ind = ind + 1
                                          
    def parse_category(self, response):
        # produtos na pagina   
        items = response.xpath('//div[@class="paginado"]//article[@class="single-product vitrine230 "]')          
        for item in items:
            url = item.xpath('.//div[@itemprop="item"]/form/div[@class="productInfo"]/div]/a[@class="prodTitle"]/@href').extract()
            urla = urljoin(response.url, link)
            request = scrapy.Request (urla, callback = self.parse_product)
            request.meta['idCategory'] = response.meta['idCategory']
            yield request

        # proxima pagina (caso exista)
        nextpage = response.xpath('//div[@class="pagination"]/ul/li/a[@class="pure-button next"]/@href').extract()
        if (nextpage):
            link = nextpage[0]
            urlb = urljoin(response.url, link)
            self.log('Next Page: {0}'.format(nextpage))
            request = scrapy.Request (urlb, callback = self.parse_category)
            request.meta['idCategory'] = response.meta['idCategory']
            yield request
          
    def parse_product (self, response):
        print response.url
        title = response.xpath('//title/text()').extract()
        self.log(u'Título: {0}'.format(title))
```

but i get the following output:

```
    PS C:\Users\Natalia Oliveira\Desktop\Be Happy\behappy\import\webscrape> scrapy crawl americanas
    2016-10-06 17:28:04 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.1.2 started (bot: webscrape)
    2016-10-06 17:28:04 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'webscrape.spiders', 'REDIRECT_ENABLED': Fal
se, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['webscrap.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'webscrape'}
    2016-10-06 17:28:04 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions:
    ['scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
    'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
    'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
    2016-10-06 17:28:05 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
    ['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.chunked.ChunkedTransferMiddleware',
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
    2016-10-06 17:28:05 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
    ['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
    'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
    'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
    'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
    'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
    2016-10-06 17:28:05 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
    []
    2016-10-06 17:28:05 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
    2016-10-06 17:28:05 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
    2016-10-06 17:28:05 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
    2016-10-06 17:28:05 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.americanas.com.br/loja/226795/alimentos-e-bebidas?WT.m
c_id=home-menuLista-alimentos/> (referer: None) 
    2016-10-06 17:28:07 [scrapy] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET http://www.americanas.com.br/loja/226795/alimentos-
e-bebidas?WT.mc_id=home-menuLista-alimentos/> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all dupli
cates)
    2016-10-06 17:28:07 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.americanas.com.br/loja/226795/alimentos-e-bebidas?WT.m
c_id=home-menuLista-alimentos/> (referer: http://www.americanas.com.br/loja/226795/alimentos-e-bebidas?WT.mc_id=home-men
uLista-alimentos/)
    2016-10-06 17:28:22 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
    2016-10-06 17:28:22 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 931,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 80585,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'dupefilter/filtered': 60,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 6, 20, 28, 22, 257000),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 4,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 6, 20, 28, 5, 346000)}
     2016-10-06 17:28:22 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

I really don't know what is wrong here, because i'm a beginner in scrapy. Here's the wrong point?
The def parse is running as expected, so, I think the error should be in def parse_category or parse_product methods.

Comment: You definitely have an error with `urla = urljoin(response.url, link)`, link is not defined. I presume it should be `urla = urljoin(response.url, url)`. Also what is `x = webscrap.items.Category(c1)` etc.. doing?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham thank you very much. You were right, the 'url' was a mistake, however, still have the same return. And about your question, the, its was just an attempt  to save a category index

Comment: you can use `print()` to see values in variables and find which variable has wrong value - this way you can find line of code which makes problem.

Comment: You have a few issues, the biggest probably being you xpath never finds a link, that is why you see the dupefilter output. You keep going back to the same base url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *xpath* is not correct and there is only one `item-menu` per page, i have removed the items logic as I don't know what they are. This will get you all the links from the *item-menu* ul, you can add back in whatever logic you like:

```
 def parse(self, response):
    for url in response.xpath('//div[@class="item-menu"]/ul/li[@class="item-linha"]/a/@href').extract():
        if not url.startswith("http"):
            url = response.urljoin(url)
        request = scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_category)
        request.meta['idCategory'] = url # add whatever here
        yield request
```

You next method is also over complicated, you don't need to worry about anything but the *anchor* tags with the `prodTitle` class:

```
def parse_category(self, response):
        # produtos na pagina
        urls = response.css('a.prodTitle::attr(href)').extract()
        for url in urls:
            request = scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_product)
            request.meta['idCategory'] = response.meta['idCategory']
            yield request
        # you want to check for the anchor with "Próxima" text
        nextpage = response.xpath(u'//ul[@class="pure-paginator acrN"]/li/a[contains(.,"Próxima")]/@href').extract_first()
        if nextpage:
            self.log(u'Next Page: {0}'.format(nextpage))
            request = scrapy.Request(nextpage, callback=self.parse_category)
            request.meta['idCategory'] = response.meta['idCategory']
            yield request

def parse_product(self, response):
    print response.url
    title = response.xpath('//title/text()').extract_first()
    self.log(u'Título: {0}'.format(title))
```

If you run it now you will see lots of output like:

```
2016-10-06 23:25:15 [americanas] DEBUG: Next Page: http://www.americanas.com.br/linha/314061/alimentos-e-bebidas/biscoitos?ofertas.offset=30
2016-10-06 23:25:15 [americanas] DEBUG: Next Page: http://www.americanas.com.br/linha/342151/alimentos-e-bebidas/azeite-e-vinagre?ofertas.offset=30
2016-10-06 23:25:15 [americanas] DEBUG: Next Page: http://www.americanas.com.br/linha/342129/alimentos-e-bebidas/barra-de-cereais?ofertas.offset=30
2016-10-06 23:25:16 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.americanas.com.br/produto/15815078/nan-comfor-1-formula-infantil-nestle-lata-800g> (referer: http://www.americanas.com.br/linha/314080/alimentos-e-bebidas/alimentacao-infantil)
http://www.americanas.com.br/produto/15815078/nan-comfor-1-formula-infantil-nestle-lata-800g
2016-10-06 23:25:16 [americanas] DEBUG: Título: Nan Comfor 1 Fórmula Infantil Nestlé Lata 800g - Americanas.com
2016-10-06 23:25:16 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.americanas.com.br/linha/316829/eletrodomesticos/adega-de-vinho> (referer: http://www.americanas.com.br/loja/226795/alimentos-e-bebidas?WT.mc_id=home-menuLista-alimentos/)
2016-10-06 23:25:16 [americanas] DEBUG: Next Page: http://www.americanas.com.br/linha/316829/eletrodomesticos/adega-de-vinho?ofertas.offset=30
2016-10-06 23:25:16 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.americanas.com.br/produto/7170286/goiabada-135g-diet-house> (referer: http://www.americanas.com.br/linha/314082/alimentos-e-bebidas/mercearia-doce)
2016-10-06 23:25:16 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.americanas.com.br/produto/9955598/adocante-em-sache-fit-caixa-com-30-unidades-de-2-5g-uniao> (referer: http://www.americanas.com.br/linha/314082/alimentos-e-bebidas/mercearia-doce)
2016-10-06 23:25:16 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.americanas.com.br/linha/285368/utilidades-domesticas/vinho> (referer: http://www.americanas.com.br/loja/226795/alimentos-e-bebidas?WT.mc_id=home-menuLista-alimentos/)
http://www.americanas.com.br/produto/7170286/goiabada-135g-diet-house
2016-10-06 23:25:16 [americanas] DEBUG: Título: Goiabada 135g - Diet House - Americanas.com
http://www.americanas.com.br/produto/9955598/adocante-em-sache-fit-caixa-com-30-unidades-de-2-5g-uniao
2016-10-06 23:25:16 [americanas] DEBUG: Título: Adoçante Em Sache Fit Caixa Com 30 Unidades De 2,5g  União - Americanas.com
2016-10-06 23:25:16 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.americanas.com.br/produto/121047374/barra-de-chocolate-ao-leite-lacta-150g-1-unidade> (referer: http://www.americanas.com.br/linha/314045/alimentos-e-bebidas/bomboniere)
2016-10-06 23:25:16 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.americanas.com.br/linha/314080/alimentos-e-bebidas/alimentacao-infantil?ofertas.offset=30> (referer: http://www.americanas.com.br/linha/314080/alimentos-e-bebidas/alimentacao-infantil)
2016-10-06 23:25:16 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.americanas.com.br/linha/314082/alimentos-e-bebidas/mercearia-doce?ofertas.offset=30> (referer: http://www.americanas.com.br/linha/314082/alimentos-e-bebidas/mercearia-doce)
2016-10-06 23:25:16 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.americanas.com.br/produto/9800047/acucar-refinado-caixa-com-400-envelopes-x-5g-uniao-premium> (referer: http://www.americanas.com.br/linha/314082/alimentos-e-bebidas/mercearia-doce)
http://www.americanas.com.br/produto/121047374/barra-de-chocolate-ao-leite-lacta-150g-1-unidade
2016-10-06 23:25:16 [americanas] DEBUG: Título: Barra de Chocolate Ao leite Lacta 150g - 1 unidade - Americanas.com
```

Comment: Exactally. Thank you so much PadraicCunningham. You encode a little different  of me but its workig very well. I will practice more, thank you again for your fast solution.